# netsh winhttp does not appear to work. Any suggestions why?

Tags: windows, proxy, lan, netsh, winhttp

I have windows 10 enterprise and when I use this command to set proxy :

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="socks=89.42.198.79:47570"
```

I get this output :

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  socks=89.42.198.79:47570
    Bypass List     :  (none)
```

and when I enter this command:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

I get same result.
but when I go to proxy setting or proxy setting in LAN setting or when I check my ip, nothing has changed and my proxy isn't changed.
I want to know what is wrong with this command and is there any similar command to this one?

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was ?